# Passing SESSION variables

Tags: php

Let's say I have a questionnaire consisting of three pages that a user is supposed to submit.
I collect variables through SESSION.
Should I pass all the variables in session from page to page repeating them or could I pass variables from page one to page three? 
For example, I have 'first name' and 'last name' on page 1, 'email' and 'address' on page 2, 'age' and 'occupation' on page 3.
Could I pass 'first name' and 'last name' from page 1 directly to page 3?
Or I will have to pass them to page 2 first and then pass them again from page 2 to page 3?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be misunderstanding what a "session variable" is.  On the user side, there's generally a cookie with a "session ID".  On the server side, there's a file containing variables and values associated with that session ID.

There is no "passing variables from page to page" - so long as the user's session cookie is maintained, **all** pages within the scope of the cookie have access to all the session variables.

Comment: Yes, I got the concept now.
Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 2):

The session variables should be persistent no matter what pages you are on.  As long as you are putting the data in the session after form 1 is submitted.

Answer (score 2):

A session value persists from page to page. Once page 1 stores it, it's accessible from any page and lasts during the entire session.